# MYSQL - Error in After Insert trigger affects the actual insert on the trigger table

Tags: mysql, trigger, foreign-key

I have two tables call it - table_1 and table_2

I have an After insert trigger on table_1 and in the trigger I insert on table_2 which has some fk constraints on another table_3.

When the insert on table_2 fails, the table_1 insert fails.

Is this normal? and Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire trigger chain constitutes one atomic operation inside a transaction -- that's "A" in ACID. So yes, this is working as designed.

If atomicity is not important to you, that is, if you are fine with the fact that `table_1` is updated but the insert into `table_2` is lost, you need to introduce error handling in your trigger, something along these lines:

```sql
create trigger table_1_trig1 after insert on table_1 
for each row
begin
 -- no-op handler that just continues; 
 -- sqlstate 23000 is the foreign key violation
 declare continue handler for sqlstate '23000' begin end;
 insert into table_2 ...;
end
```

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d5823c8afe24a49f12d4b0eff4cc3dde)

The condition `for sqlstate '23000'` is the SQL standard equivalent of the MySQL-specific `for 1452`. If you want to ignore *all* errors when inserting into `table_2` just use `for sqlexception` instead.

So yes, there is a workaround. However, one should think twice before going that route; if one doesn't care if rows are inserted into `table_2` or not, why bother inserting them in the first place? May be take another look at your business logic.

---

Note that such error handling may not necessarily work in other DBMSes; MySQL treats trigger code much like stored procedures invoked upon DML execution, with all associated overhead.